# How to extract only a paritcular datetime from the webresponse and match it with the given date time?

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am using following regular expression to extract date from a html page:

```
(((0?[1-9]|[1-2][1-9]|[123]0|31)(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)(0?[13578]|1[02])(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)\d{4})|((0?[2-9]|[0?1]1|[1-2][1-9]|[123]0)(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)(0?[13456789]|1[0-2])(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)(\d{4}))|((0?[1-8]|[1-2][0-8]|[0?1]9)(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)(0?2)(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)(\d{4}))|(29(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)0?2(/|.|'|:|,|\s|-)((19(0[048]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|([2-9]\d{1}([2468][048]|[13579][26]|00)))))(.*|\w*|\s*)([01]?\d)|(2[0-3])(:|\.|-|'|\/|\s)[0-5]?\d{2}"); //dd-mm-yyyy hhh:mm:ss
```

above regular expression extracts date that is in dd mm yyyy h mm ss format with different separators.

what i get as output from match.value is something like below:

```
11/09/2013&nbsp;at&nbsp;09:48</b></td> that is it matches everything from the response that follows the match.
```

but i only want that the result of match.value should be only like this:

```
11/09/2013 09:48
```

so what my expression basically does is that it matches everything that follows the date which is not my requirement i need that it should only match date and time mentioned in the text box.

kindly help me how can i change my regex to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your logic (<[^<]+?>)+ to remove the HTML tags and (&[^;]+?;)+ for &nbsp.

EDIT:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "<[^<]+?>" ,"");
text = Regex.Replace(text, "(&[^;]+?;)+", "");
text = text.Trim();
text = text.Remove(17);
```

Comment: but where do i need to add this regexs?

Comment: <link href="http://www.mhpa.co.uk/reports.css" rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" CHARSET="ISO-8859-1">

<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100%>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align=right><b>11/09/2013&nbsp;at&nbsp;09:48</b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<center>
<table border="1" bordercolor="silver" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width=100>ETA</th>
<th width=100>Ship Name</th>
<th width=80>From port</th>
<th width=80>To berth</th>
<th width=130>Agent</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>11/09/2013 at 09:00&nbsp;</td>
<td>SONANGOL KALANDULA&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

Comment: Well if the page is the same format for each shipment a recommend using something like text = Regex.Replace(text, "<[^<]+?>" ,"");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "(&[^;]+?;)+", "");
            text = text.Trim();
            text = text.Remove(17);

Comment: if u can suggest a regex in general with can work with any sort of page that is what ever the page content be it should extract given date and time for example if the string is str = "hi today is 11/09/2013 the meeting is scheduled at 13:00:00" and the if i give input as 11/09/2013 13:00:00 it should match.